# CPU usage is stuck at 14%

Tags: cpu-usage

I have a problem. Every minute or so, my CPU usage just jumps to 14%. Then, everything lags out, the sound is distorted, and my mouse responds with a delay. After around 30 seconds it goes back to normal. Only if I restart my computer it doesn't happen, but after a few hours, it comes back again. It has been troubling me for around 2 years! It is really annoying.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

edit: I have an ASUS laptop with Windows 10 Home 64 bit

Comment: 14% is normal and not too high.  It appears the machine may have hung.  After restart, look in Reliability Monitor to see if there is an error coincident with the machine hanging

Comment: What CPU do you have? 14% would be a common value for a Quad-Core CPU with SMT/Hyperthreading (=8 threads) and one CPU core fully occupied by a process.

Comment: Windows Admin Tools, Resource Monitor will graph CPU usage by process over time (15 to 30 minutes) and is very handy for sorting this out.

Answer (score 0):

When this starts next time, keep the task manager open and sorted by %. You might locate the suspect process there.

Comment: I tried that out, but when it happened, every process just dropped a little down with %, for example, one of my processes had 9,6%, and after that happened, it dropped down to around 3%, and later went back up to 9%

Comment: ProcessExplorer from Microsoft SysInternals or Process Hacker which is an open source tool might help you understand this better. 

CPU usage jumping to 14% but individual processes dropping down percentage points may mean that a hidden process is taking up the CPU time. Were you using Task Manager in administrator mode? Try running the tools I have mentioned above in administrator mode for more detailed information.

Because it is random and short lived and happens after some time, failing hard disk may be one possibility.

Answer (score -2):

just downgrade your bios to initial bios version
then it will work fine

command to do this is go to winflash directory first and then type "Winflash /nodate"
and press enter.
then it will allow you to downgrade your bios in asus laptop

Comment: That's a bold claim, that downgrading the BIOS will solve CPU load issues. What evidence do you have this is the case?